# Why does this Prolog program not terminate?

Tags: list, recursion, prolog, logic, constraints

I’m new to Prolog and I wanted to write a simple predicate that checks if a given value is in a list.

I do not know exactly if the way I was taught lists is correct. I was taught that it is a car/cdr or head/tail relation (familiar from LISP/Haskell) that is “matched on” with `[X|Xs]`.

I first tried with this program:

```pl
in([ ], _) :- false.
in([X|_], X).
in([_|Xs], X) :- in(Xs, X).
```

Now this program doesn’t terminate if fed with any query that should return `true.` (e.g. `?- in([1, 2], 2).`). Instead, it *does* print out `true` (without a period) and then hangs.

I considered that perhaps, after encountering a unifying rule at `in([X|_], X).` Prolog continues to search for other values that unify with `in([_|Xs], X)`. It is unclear to me why this would not terminate since the recursive descent always reduces the argument. Nonetheless, I then attempted this program:

```pl
in([ ], _) :- false.
in([X|_], X).
in([X|Xs], Y) :- in(Xs, Y), X \= Y.
```

I hoped this would prevent Prolog from descending on the other rule but this preserved the previous behaviour. I then remembered that the order of predicates in a rule matters, so I attempted this:

```pl
in([ ], _) :- false.
in([X|_], X).
in([X|Xs], Y) :- X \= Y, in(Xs, Y).
```

The behaviour prevailed. In frustration and suspecting I had completely misunderstood Prolog evaluation I tried reversing all clauses, to the most curious effect:

```pl
in([X|Xs], Y) :- X \= Y, in(Xs, Y).
in([X|_], X).
in([ ], _) :- false.
```

This now causes Prolog to terminate *if the list is empty or the element is found at the head*, so:

```
?- in([ ], 10).
false.

?- in([1, 2], 1).
true.

?- in([1, 2], 2).
true
```

and then it hangs.

I don’t understand how such behaviour comes about. What is Prolog doing?

I am using SWI-Prolog 9.1.10

Comment: "without a period" means it is waiting for you to tell it to try to find an alternate solution (which may just be a different way of deriving the same solution).  In your case, that attempt should fail.

Comment: What does this mean? If it has found `true`, what other solutions can there be?

Comment: It has another rule it can try; only by trying it can it determine that it will fail.

Comment: How do I tell it to do either of these? I have now noticed that pressing enter does make it stop.

Comment: You don't; it will try whichever ones it can unify with the head.  And entering `;` (I think) tells it to try looking for an alternate solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behaviour, it pauses when it has found a solution. It keeps track of the paths through the code as it searches, and when there are still unexplored paths it prompts you for what to do next ("hangs"). Press `?` (question mark) at that point, and SWI Prolog will show you the options:

```
  Possible actions:
  ; (n,r,space,TAB): redo              | t:         trace&redo
  *:                 show choicepoint  | c (a,RET): stop
  w:                 write             | p:         print
  b:
```

Semi-colon, space are the ones which continue searching ("redo"). `c` and `a`bort and RETurn will stop there.

> If it has found true, what other solutions can there be?

You know there are no more, it doesn't - it's not intelligent. It can only report finding no more solutions if it can finish searching the entire code. Try `?- member(2, [1,2,3,2,1]).` and then try `?- member(X, [1,2,3]).` and see how they find more than one solution.